# biblatex (authoryear-ibid) InCollection with editors between main title and booktitle with "in:"

Tags: biblatex

I would like to have the **InCollection** (also: InProceedings) source type to be changed up.

So I would like to have

- *main title*
- an "in:" behind the (main) source title
- the editor name after said source title
- then an ":"
- *booktitle*

All the rest is good to go and should not be changed please.

An example of what it should be like is here:

> **Brandt, A. von/Hoffmann, E. (1987):**
>   Die nordischen Länder von der Mitte des 11. Jahrhunderts bis 1448, in: Seibt, F./Smith, J. (editors): Europa im Hoch und
>   Spätmittelalter, no. 2, 4th ed., Klett-Cotta, Stuttgart, pp. 884–917.

The status quo, produced by the MWE, looks like this currently:

> **Brandt, A. von/Hoffmann, E. (1987):**
>   Die nordischen Länder von der Mitte des 11. Jahrhunderts bis 1448, in: Europa im Hochund
>   Spätmittelalter, Seibt, F./Smith, J. (editors), no. 2, 4th ed., Klett-Cotta, Stuttgart,
>   pp. 884–917.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]
{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}


\usepackage[
language=auto,
style=authoryear-ibid,
backend=bibtex,
hyperref=true,
isbn=false,
doi=false,
citereset=chapter,
maxcitenames=3,
dashed=false,
sorting=nyt,
firstinits=true,
ibidtracker=true,
maxbibnames=99
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}

%% comma after every item for bibiliography entries
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

%%  parentheses around year in references
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
\iffieldundef{labelyear}
{}
{%
\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
\printtext[parens]{%
\printfield{labelyear}%
\printfield{extrayear}}}}}

%% correct order of publisher and location
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
\newunit
\printlist{publisher}%
\newunit
\printlist{location}%
\newunit}

%%  right order of words 'volume' und 'issue' with comma in front
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}% THIS LINE CHANGED to add comma
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

%taken from standard.bbx
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \printtext{%   REMOVED parenthesis here
    \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{date}}
      {\printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \usebibmacro{date}}}%
  \newunit}

%% bold bibliography "label" followed by colon and linebreak
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\mkbibbold\bgroup}
\xapptobibmacro{date+extrayear}{\addcolon\egroup}{}{}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\par\nobreak}

%% linebreak before URLs and colon before date of last visit
\xpretobibmacro{url+urldate}{\setunit{\newunitpunct\par\nobreak}}{}{}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
urlseen = {last visit\addcolon}
}

%% colon before date of last visit
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\addcolon\space#1}}

%% no indent
\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt} 

%% one empty line between to bib-entries
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\baselineskip} %% \baselineskip gibt hier an, dass Zeilenabstand unterhalb des Absatzes der dokumentweite Abstand ist

%% ``(editor)'' or ``(editors)''
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}
\xpatchbibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}{\printtext}{\printtext[parens]}{}{}

%%  ``(editor)'' or ``(editors)'' instead of ``(ed. by)''
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
byeditor = {editor},%
byeditor = {editors},%
issue  = {\lowercase{i}ss\adddot},%
}

%% edition behind series number ("no.")
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \iffieldequalstr{edition}{1}
    {\clearfield{edition}}
    {\savefield*{edition}{\savededition}%
     \clearfield{edition}}}

\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \restorefield{edition}{\savededition}
  \printfield{series}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit}

%% all titles in references in normal formatting
\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{#1\isdot} 

%% annul format of any (main) title in bibliography and add comma+space
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1\addcomma\addspace} 

%% annul format of any other (parent) titles in bibliography
\DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{#1\addcomma\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1\addcomma\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{issuetitle}{#1\addcomma\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{maintitle}{#1\addcomma\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{proceedingstitle}{#1\addcomma\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{collectiontitle}{#1\addcomma\addspace}
%new
\DeclareFieldFormat*{volume}{\bibstring{volume}~#1\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{issue}{\bibstring{issue}~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1} %comment to leave number as before
\DeclareFieldFormat*{series}{{#1}\addcomma\space} %comment to leave number as before

%% Names: Lastname, Firstname
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\AtBeginBibliography{%
    %% only slash signs between names
    \renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addslash}
    \renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addslash}
    %% only slash signs between multiple locations
    \renewcommand{\multilistdelim}{\addslash}
    \renewcommand{\finallistdelim}{\addslash}
}

\begin{filecontents*}{lit.bib}
@InCollection{brandt,
  options     = {useprefix=false},
  hyphenation     = {german},
  author      = {von Brandt, Ahasver and Hoffmann, Erich},
  editor      = {Seibt, Ferdinand and Smith, John},
  title       = {Die nordischen L{\"a}nder von der Mitte des 11.~Jahrhunderts bis 1448},
  booktitle  = {Europa im Hoch- und Sp{\"a}tmittelalter},
  number      = {2},
    edition = {4},
  publisher   = {Klett-Cotta},
  location    = {Stuttgart},
  date        = {1987},
  pages       = {884--917}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{lit.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Place holder for \verb+InCollection+.\footcite[See][p. 5--11]{brandt}
\end{itemize}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made an attempt on my own and it seems to work so far.

- I took the definition of `{maintitle+booktitle}` from the file `standard.bbx` and simply copy and pasted it as `\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+booktitle}`
- I commented out `\usebibmacro{booktitle}%` from said code bit
- I then added

  ```
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}
  \usebibmacro{booktitle}
  ```

  to the already included redefinition of `{byeditor+others}` (see MWE above or below), which resulted in:

  ```
  \documentclass[12pt,
  a4paper
  ]
  {scrreprt}

  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

  \usepackage{lmodern}
  \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}


  \usepackage[
  language=auto,
  style=authoryear-ibid,
  backend=bibtex,
  hyperref=true,
  isbn=false,
  dashed=false,
  doi=false,
  citereset=chapter,
  maxcitenames=3,
  sorting=nyt,
  firstinits=true,
  ibidtracker=true,
  maxbibnames=99
  ]{biblatex}
  \usepackage{xpatch}

  %% comma after every item for bibiliography entries
  \renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

  %%  parentheses around year in references
  \renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
  {}
  {%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
  \printtext[parens]{%
  \printfield{labelyear}%
  \printfield{extrayear}}}}}

  %% correct order of publisher and location
  \renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \newunit
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{location}%
  \newunit}

  %%  right order of words 'volume' und 'issue' with comma in front
  \renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
    \usebibmacro{journal}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \iffieldundef{series}
      {}
      {\newunit
       \printfield{series}%
       \setunit{\addspace}}%
    \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}% THIS LINE CHANGED to add comma
    \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
    \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
    \usebibmacro{issue}%
    \newunit}
  %taken from standard.bbx
  \renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
    \printtext{%   REMOVED parenthesis here
      \iffieldundef{issue}
        {\usebibmacro{date}}
        {\printfield{issue}%
         \setunit*{\addspace}%
         \usebibmacro{date}}}%
    \newunit}

  %% booktitle after editors
  \renewbibmacro*{maintitle+booktitle}{%
    \iffieldundef{maintitle}
      {}
      {\usebibmacro{maintitle}%
       \newunit\newblock
       \iffieldundef{volume}
         {}
         {\printfield{volume}%
          \printfield{part}%
          \setunit{\addcolon\space}}}%
    %\usebibmacro{booktitle}%
    \newunit}

  %% bold bibliography "label" followed by colon and linebreak
  \renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\mkbibbold\bgroup}
  \xapptobibmacro{date+extrayear}{\addcolon\egroup}{}{}
  \renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\par\nobreak}

  %% linebreak before URLs and colon before date of last visit
  \xpretobibmacro{url+urldate}{\setunit{\newunitpunct\par\nobreak}}{}{}
  \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  urlseen = {last visit\addcolon}
  }

  %% colon before date of last visit
  \DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\addcolon\space#1}}

  %% no indent
  \setlength{\bibhang}{0pt} 

  %% one empty line between to bib-entries
  \setlength{\bibitemsep}{\baselineskip} %% \baselineskip gibt hier an, dass Zeilenabstand unterhalb des Absatzes der dokumentweite Abstand ist

  %% ``(editor)'' or ``(editors)''
  \renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
    \ifnameundef{editor}
      {}
      {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
       \setunit{\addspace}%
       \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
       \clearname{editor}%
       \newunit}%
    \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
    \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}
      \setunit{\addcolon\space}
      \usebibmacro{booktitle}}
  \xpatchbibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}{\printtext}{\printtext[parens]}{}{}

  %%  ``(editor)'' or ``(editors)'' instead of ``(ed. by)''
  \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  byeditor = {editor},%
  byeditor = {editors},%
  issue  = {\lowercase{i}ss\adddot},%
  }

  %% edition behind number (no.)
  \AtEveryBibitem{%
    \iffieldequalstr{edition}{1}
      {\clearfield{edition}}
      {\savefield*{edition}{\savededition}%
       \clearfield{edition}}}
  \renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
    \restorefield{edition}{\savededition}
    \printfield{series}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \printfield{number}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{edition}%
    \newunit}

  %% all titles in references in normal formatting
  \DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{#1\isdot} 

  %% annul format of any (main) title in bibliography and add comma+space
  \DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1\addcomma\addspace} 

  %% annul format of any other (parent) titles in bibliography
  \DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{#1\addcomma\addspace}
  \DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1\addcomma\addspace}
  \DeclareFieldFormat*{issuetitle}{#1\addcomma\addspace}
  \DeclareFieldFormat*{maintitle}{#1\addcomma\addspace}
  \DeclareFieldFormat*{proceedingstitle}{#1\addcomma\addspace}
  \DeclareFieldFormat*{collectiontitle}{#1\addcomma\addspace}
  %new
  \DeclareFieldFormat*{volume}{\bibstring{volume}~#1\space}
  \DeclareFieldFormat*{issue}{\bibstring{issue}~#1}
  \DeclareFieldFormat*{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1} %comment to leave number as before
  \DeclareFieldFormat*{series}{{#1}\addcomma\space} %comment to leave number as before

  %% Names: Lastname, Firstname
  \DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
  \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

  \AtBeginBibliography{%
      %% only slash signs between names
      \renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addslash}
      \renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addslash}
      %% only slash signs between multiple locations
      \renewcommand{\multilistdelim}{\addslash}
      \renewcommand{\finallistdelim}{\addslash}
  }

  \begin{filecontents*}{lit.bib}
  @InCollection{brandt,
    options     = {useprefix=false},
    hyphenation     = {german},
    author      = {von Brandt, Ahasver and Hoffmann, Erich},
    editor      = {Seibt, Ferdinand and Smith, John},
    title       = {Die nordischen L{\"a}nder von der Mitte des 11.~Jahrhunderts bis 1448},
    booktitle  = {Europa im Hoch- und Sp{\"a}tmittelalter},
    number      = {2},
      edition = {4},
    publisher   = {Klett-Cotta},
    location    = {Stuttgart},
    date        = {1987},
    pages       = {884--917}
  }
  \end{filecontents*}
  \addbibresource{lit.bib}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{itemize}
      \item Place holder for \verb+InCollection+.\footcite[See][p. 5--11]{brandt}
  \end{itemize}

  \printbibliography
  \end{document}
  ```

Comment: Your attempt seems to work, but because of the various formatting changes unrelated to the problem at hand it's hard to spot what you *did* change actually. I'd upvote this if you provided a short explanation so that others with a similar problem can benefit.

Comment: Ok I edited my answer. I hope the notes are ok?

Comment: Yes, that's better, so +1.